# Why there are many connections in this case (MySQLNonTransientConnectionException)

Tags: mysql, select, prepared-statement

I am getting an exception using `PreparedStatement` to select.

```
Got an exception accessing TestCase data! null

Problem to connect.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Too many connections
```

Here is my code:

```
public Integer getTypeByInputAndProblemId(String inputTestCase, Long problemId) {

    String sql = "SELECT type FROM test_case where problem_id= ? and input= ?";

    Integer type = 0;

    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setLong(1, problemId);
        ps.setString(2, inputTestCase);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            type = new Integer(rs.getInt("type"));
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception accessing TestCase data! " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return type;
}
```

In line `PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)`;
my problem is because connection sometimes is Null (the debug shows this).

I'm guessing this is because of many connections, but I don't know why this is happening.

I would like some help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue happens because your server is reaching the max number of multiple connections accepted by your MySQL Server.

First, you need to see if you have a proper number configured in MySQL for multiple connections: [**max_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections). **If this look low to you, you can increase this number in order to "fix" this issue.**

Secondly, if the number makes sense, you're probably using more connections than you think you are. **Probably because you're opening connections in your application and not closing them.**

Check how many multiple connections your server have used so far.

```
show status like 'Max_used_connections';
```

This number is reset when you restart your database service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was the second possibility you talked about. I was creating a new connection, instead of using the same, everytime I called this method (and this is a lot). So, now I am just using the same connection to access db. But I have a doubt, is this good or I should close and open everytime I need?

Comment: Yes, if you can open a persistent connection and use the same one, that's the best way to go on most scenarios.